# Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: JohnDoe12>>": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,default=None, 
                   null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128) #actual creator's name
```

In the forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['user']
        # fields = '__all__'
        model = models.Profile
```

In views.py

```
def TestPage(request):

    form = ProfileForm

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_instance=form.save(commit=False)
            form_instance.user = request.user
            form_instance.save()
            return render(request,'test.html')
        else:
            print('ERROR FORM INVALID')

    return render(request,'accounts/update_profile.html',{'form':form})
```

I think there is an issue with the line form_instance.user = request.user. I am getting an errorCannot assign ">": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance. To Profile.user I want save current user. could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
form_instance.user = request.user.pk
```

If not work then add your models.py

Comment: Comment this line `exclude = ['user']` and uncomment this line ` fields = '__all__' `

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
form_instance.user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

But also make sure that user is logged in before coming to this line(Like using [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) or [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin)).