# Django ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <CustomUser: >>": "Booking.user" must be a "Customer" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

The objective is simple: I'm building a car rental platform where customers can place an order for a car. The simple 'order' contains the car, start, and end-dates. The form should automatically save the authenticated user as the creator.

It uses a CreateView with this code:

```
class BookingCreate(CreateView):
    model = Booking
    fields = ['car', 'start_date', 'end_date']

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The form works fine, but when submitted, it raises this error:

> ValueError at /rentals/booking/create
> Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <CustomUser: Test2 Two>>": "Booking.user" must be a "Customer" instance.

I've looked up previous answers, and the best solution came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220778/cannot-assign-simplelazyobject-for-customuser-model-in-django) thread, which recommended using this code instead

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
     form.instance.user = Booking.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
         return super().form_valid(form)
```

However, this change returns a slightly different error:

> ValueError at /rentals/booking/create
> Cannot query "Test2 Two": Must be "Customer" instance.
> I have a customUser Model and a "customer" model that inherits from it.

For additional context, I am using a customUser model. Because I have multiple user types (in particular (car) Owners and Customers), I use a special table with boolean fields to mark each type as True based on the registration form they use per this [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) tutorial.

Here's the relevant code (there's a lot, so I've only added the relevant parts):

**models.py**

```
from accounts.models import CustomUser

class User(CustomUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    

class Owner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField('Car', blank=True)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rental:customer-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{ self.user.first_name } { self.user.last_name }' 

class Booking(models.Model):
    """Stores the bookings, for example when it was made, the booking date, and the car ID."""

    # Unique ID for this booking.
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="Automatically generated unique ID. Do not change.")
    user = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    ...
```

---

**Solution and extra resources for future explorers**

Both answers below helped, but the issue kept coming back. The permanent solution was this line of code:

```
  def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = Customer.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

As alluded to in the question above, this is a common problem. So here are three other threads to look at, each with great answers:

[ValueError at /post/new/ Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject:<User: chetan>>": "Post.author" must be a "User" instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780434/valueerror-at-post-new-cannot-assign-simplelazyobjectuser-chetan-pos)

[Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: XXX>>": "Comment.user" must be a "MyProfile" instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567667/cannot-assign-simplelazyobject-user-xxx-comment-user-must-be-a-mypro)

[Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: JohnDoe12>>": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175494/cannot-assign-simplelazyobject-user-johndoe12-profile-user-must-be-a)

Answer (score 1):

Your self.request.user (or the user you're logged in as) seems to be the CustomUser instance, but you're trying to assign the User instance to the Booking. Though it has the same fields (as it inherits from CustomUser class), it is a different object.

I think you want to make the CustomUser an abstract model?
You should add abstract to the CustomUser class.
See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

```
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then you would also need to select the correct user model in you'r settings like:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User' for example

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Also in the second option you're assigning the Booking instead of the related user. Do this instead:

```
def form_valid(self, form): 
    form.instance.user = Booking.objects.get(user=self.request.user).user 
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: And regarding the first part, the customUser model inherits the AbstractUser model. Does that do the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, the AbstractUser model from django also has the abstract = True in the meta class.

Comment: Why don’t you just put is_customer and other other fields in your CustomUser and reference that model ? Also you don’t really need seperate models for Customer and and Owner. In theory I guess your user can be an owner and a customer at the same time. And you can put a foreignkey to user on your cars model. Not sure if in your use case the Car could have multiple owners.

Comment: Right now you have 4 tables in your database that kinda all are users. It’s both unnecessary and will make things complicated when you add more features. If you need to add more specific fields for a user, let’s say a ownerprofile, or whatever, you just create a seperate model for that and add a foreignkey to the user, but that’s all far beyond the scope of your initial question.

Comment: "In theory I guess your user can be an owner and a customer at the same time. And you can put a foreignkey to user on your cars model. " That's right! "Not sure if in your use case the Car could have multiple owners." No. The point is to have a car linked to an owner account.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of the question, but you're suggestion is really helpful! What do you propose? Just deleting them and using the ForeignKey to the CustomUser (which is currently in its separate accounts app)? Wouldn't multiple foreignkeys for owner and customer all pointing to the same car clash?

Comment: Yeah the CustomUser is the only user you need. Cars have 2 foreignkeys to user. 1 would have related_name=owner and the other related_name=renter. That’s perfectly fine.

Comment: I don’t know how far you wanna go with this, but what I would do: a car could also belong to a company, which might have multiple users. So you could create a profile model and link the cars to the profiles of the users/companies 

Comment: It's a little late, but I want to thank you for the advice (forgot to do so earlier). Got rid of the three extra account models, and the system still works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)  and you need to assign `user` not `Booking` instance so:

```py
def form_valid(self, form): 
    form.instance.user=get_object_or_404(Booking,user=self.request.user).user 
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Still raising the same error: "Cannot query "Test2 Two": Must be "Customer" instance. (Test2 is the test user I created)

Comment: @Rene Use `get_object_or_404(Customer, user=self.request.user)` instead and check it.

Comment: @Rene You haven't replied yet.

Comment: Oh yes! I tried that and it worked, but the problem reappeared. I added the solution I used as an edit in the question